Indifference curves given preference relation
Let's say I have a preference relation on $ℝ^2$ given by
$$x≥y \leftrightarrow  x_1+x_2 ≥ y_1+y_2$$
So, from my understanding, the bundle x is preferred at least as much as the bundle y if and only if the quantity of x is as least as big as the quantity of y. I want to draw a indifference curve that illustrates this, but I am not sure how, given that it is a weak preference, and not a strict one. I have only drawn indifference curves earlier when I have been given utility functions. So my question is, how does the indifference curve (if it is possible to draw one) for this preference relation look like?

You do have a utility function in sight: $u(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2$.

So it is perfect substitutes, correct?

Yes, that's exactly right.
